Elements added via HTML string disable onclicks/event listeners of previous elements
Elements added via HTML string disable onclicks/event listeners of previous elements
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eptcrwfd/37/
The solution is putting onclick declarations in a setTimeout on a minimal time like that
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("element-id").onclick = () => {
  console.log(1)
  }
})

but it doesn't seem like the best way and i still want to know what causes this behavior in the first place

Lines like document.body.innerHTML +=   "<button id='button4' class='button'>button4</button>" will remove the previously added html codes. What are you trying to do by this ?

@brk so its just how that works, i see. I wanted to make creation of html elements more compact by replacing html object declarations with strings, but haven't found much about their differences

Event listener are removed because with document.body.innerHTML += you first retrieve the HTML, add a string, and then set the inner HTML to the new combined string. It is as if you exchanged the inner HTML completely. Instead of += you can use insertAdjacentHTML(), see: https://jsfiddle.net/ogwyL8p7/

The expression document.body.innerHTML += ... is not as elegant or efficient as you might think. It is in fact a shorthand notation for

get me the so far existing DOM content as an HTML string (without any event listeners that might already have been defined!)
add the string after the += operator to it and
parse the resulting string again

This is not only very slow but will also delete  all previously assigned event listeners.
A safer and more efficient method of adding new chunks of HTML code to an existing element would be
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","... new HTML code"). This will leave the previously constructed DOM intact, including all event listeners.
In the following snippet I replaced all your += expressions with the insertAdjacentHTML() calls and now it works.


function addButtons(){
  const a = document.createElement("button")
  a.innerHTML = "button1"
  a.className = "button"
  a.id = "button-1"
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  //works only when done this way
  setTimeout(()=>{
  document.getElementById("button-1").onclick = ()=>
  {console.log(1)}
  })
  
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
  "<button id='button2' class='button'>button2</button>")
  
  document.getElementById("button2").onclick = ()=>{console.log(2)}
}
function addButtons1(){
const a = document.createElement("button")
  a.innerHTML = "button3"
  a.className = "button"
  //works when button4 is absent
  a.addEventListener("click", ()=>{console.log(3)})
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
  "<button id='button4' class='button'>button4</button>")
  //works
  document.getElementById("button4").onclick = ()=>{console.log(4)}
}
function addButtons2(){
const a = document.createElement("button")
  a.innerHTML = "button5"
  a.className = "button"
  //works
  a.onclick = ()=>{console.log(5)}
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  
  
const b = document.createElement("button")
  b.innerHTML = "button6"
  b.className = "button"
  //works
  b.onclick = ()=>{console.log(6)}
  document.body.appendChild(b)
}

addButtons()
addButtons1()
addButtons2()



However, your are making life too hard for yourself. Try using "delegated event assignments" instead:


document.body.addEventListener("click"
,ev=>{
 const el=ev.target;
 if(el.classList.contains("btn")){
  console.log(`click on button ${el.name}`);
}});
function addButtons(btnDefs){
 document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",btnDefs.map(([txt,nam])=>
  `<button name="${nam}" class="btn">${txt}</button>`).join(""));

}

addButtons([["one","btn1"],["two","btn2"]]);
addButtons([["three","btn3"],["four","btn4"]]);
addButtons([["five","btn5"],["six","btn6"]]);



The "click" event-listener on the document.body is defined before the actual buttons are defined. A "click" event will trigger for direct or indirect children of the body that have a class "btn". It is up to you to make this selection in the if clause if(el.classList.contains("btn")) more or less strict.
